# How to remove newline characters from string in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

For some reason, none of the solutions previously posted about this seem to answer my question.

I am reading in an excel page with 150+ sheets. I am looping through them and preparing the data to be concatenated together.  (doing things like deleting unneeded/blank columns, and transforming some data)  However, for some reason, I cannot get rid of any of the newline characters, no matter what I try.  Here are some variations that I've tried so you can see what DIDN'T work.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\agray\Downloads')

sheets_dict = pd.read_excel('2022_Advanced_Control.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
df_list = list(sheets_dict.values())
df_list_clean = []
```

The top part stays the same, this loop portion is what changes.

```
for df in df_list:
    df.columns = [c.replace(' ', '_') for c in df.columns]

    df.drop(df.columns.difference(['Prescription_Drug_Name','Drug_Tier', 'Drug_Notes']), 1, inplace=True)
    df.drop(df.tail(3).index, inplace=True)
    df.loc[:, 'Prescription_Drug_Name'] = df.loc[:, 'Prescription_Drug_Name'].replace("\n", "", inplace=True)
    df_list_clean.append(df)
```

This gives me a column that has nothing but blank values.

Here's another way I tried

```
for df in df_list:
    df.columns = [c.replace(' ', '_') for c in df.columns]

    df.drop(df.columns.difference(['Prescription_Drug_Name','Drug_Tier', 'Drug_Notes']), 1, inplace=True)
    df.drop(df.tail(3).index, inplace=True)
    df['Prescription_Drug_Name'] = df['Prescription_Drug_Name'].replace(r'\n','', regex=True, inplace=True)
    df_list_clean.append(df)
```

This version is only applying to a copy, so none of the changes it says it's making are actually being made to my df.  Any ideas how to get rid of all these "/n" characters in my column?  Thanks!

Comment: `df['Prescription_Drug_Name'].str.strip()`?

Comment: That only removes newline characters from the beginning and end of string.  I have strings that look like this:  AAAAAA/nBBBBBBBB/nCCCCCCCCCCCCC

@Corralien

Comment: If you use `inplace=True`. you **must not** use `df['Prescription_Drug_Name'] = `

Comment: `/n` is not newline. Newline is `\n`.

Comment: the /n was a typo.  all my text data is \n.

Comment: Could I get an example of a line of code that can help?  I used your suggestions, but I'm getting errors, even after importing the re module for the sub method you're using? @Corralien

Comment: Try to use the `str.replace` instead of `replace`. It worked for your example.

Comment: @Corralien That did it.  post this as an answer, and i'll give you credit.

Comment: I had already done it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.strip()`:

```
df['Prescription_Drug_Name'] = df['Prescription_Drug_Name'].str.replace(r'\n', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I always advise against `inplace=True`. Make an explicit copy where you mean to.
*This version is only applying to a copy, so none of the changes... being made to my df*. Why don't you clone your data like this:

```
for df in df_list:
    clean = df.copy()
    clean.columns = [c.replace(' ', '_') for c in df.columns]

    clean = clean.drop(df.columns.difference(['Prescription_Drug_Name','Drug_Tier', 'Drug_Notes']), 1)

    # drop last three rows
    clean = clean.iloc[:-3]

    # modify column, remove `inplace` here
    clean['Prescription_Drug_Name'] = clean['Prescription_Drug_Name'].replace(r'\n','', regex=True)
    df_list_clean.append(clean)
```

That being said, all of the above can be chained, so you can do something like this:

```
for df in df_list
    clean = (df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'))
               .reindex(['Prescription_Drug_Name','Drug_Tier', 'Drug_Notes'], axis=1).dropna(axis=0, how='all')   # select only the columns
               .iloc[:-3]
               .assign(Prescription_Drug_Name=lambda x: x.replace(r'\n', '', regex=True)
             )
    df_list_clean.append(clean)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is actually unexpectedly useful. I really like that idea of using a copy within my loop.  That'll save me some headaches of figuring out if a change was made to the original or a copy.